# Is it correct to use manual ID binding in backbone.js for children to parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm doing an app that basically works like the facebook wall.

Essentially Posts and Comments.

It's working, but in order to render the CommentView, I'm using code similar to this in my Post Template

```
<div class="wall-post"> 
    <div class="wall-post-content">${PostContent}</div>        
    <div class="wall-post-comments" id="wall-post-comments-${PostId}"></div>
</div>
```

Then I use the id of the comment area for that post like this.

```
var comment_view = new PostCommentView({ model: post.get("Comments") });
this.$('#wall-post-comments-'+ post.get("PostId")).append($(comment_view.render()));
```

This works, but something tells me I shouldn't be manually binding against my own ID. I feel I should be doing something clever with this.el ?

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

I'm using BackBone Relational to manage the relationships.

//EDIT

As requested some more of the implementation

//Some functions relating to click evens and functionality removed, as I don't think they relate to my question.

```
PostModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
urlRoot: '/api/post',
idAttribute: 'PostId',
relations: [{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'Comments',
    relatedModel: 'CommentModel',
    reverseRelation: {
        key: 'Post',
        includeInJSON: 'PostId'
    }
}]
});


CommentModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/comment',
    idAttribute: 'PostId'
});


PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/post',
    model: PostModel
});


PostListView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'div',

className: 'PostListView',

initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'render_thread_summary', 'on_submit', 'on_thread_created', 'on_error');
    this.model.bind('reset', this.render); 
    this.model.bind('change', this.render); 
    this.model.bind('add', this.render_thread_summary); 
},
 template: $('#wall-post-template').html(),

render: function() {
    $(this.el).html($(this.template).tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));

    this.model.forEach(this.render_thread_summary);
    return $(this.el).html();
},
render_thread_summary: function(post) {
        var comment_view = new PostCommentView({ model: post.get("Comments") });
        this.$('#wall-post-comments-'+ post.get("PostId")).append($(comment_view.render()));
}
});


PostCommentView = Backbone.View.extend({   

initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'on_click');
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
},

template: $('#wall-comments-template').html(),
render: function() {
    var html = $(this.el).html($(this.template).tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
    return html;
}
});
```

Comment: To confirm, I don't really understand this.el yet.

Comment: Can you post your implementation for PostCommentView and its model?

Comment: Posted, thanks for taking the time with this :) You can see my code has basically come from the backbone relational tutorial so far.

Comment: Essentially the questions is, should I store the id of elements on the page inside them, using HTML5 data tags for example, or does backbone manage all these items on the page for me?

Comment: Backbone manages them for you - see my reply below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was greatly underusing the this.el reference. There is no need to generally use id's for most things on the page, as within a view you can just reference $(this.el) and then reference from that part of the page. $(".className", this.el) will select any class's with in the item on the page. el is essentially a reference to the area on the page where the view was rendered to. It's really clean once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started digging into Backbone (and haven't done anything with Backbone Relational yet), so with that in mind here are my 2 cents:

- Backbone defines id's for its Models, so no need to define your own id attr. If you inspect into a model instance, you'll see its id even if it's not specifically defined in your impl.
- It seems to me that you're missing a comments collection, made up by single comment models. Then attach model events within your views appropriately. That way you wouldn't have to manage your comment view rendering manually (it's all done by Backbone based on event triggers).

If you haven't looked into the BB sample Todos app, I'd suggest giving it a look - that should help you design your comment(s) model and view better.

[todos.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html)

[todos app](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) - Use Fire/ChromeBug to inspect the code

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey. I can't look into this exactly and what i've gone with so far with html5 data attributes is working well. The problem is I sometimes need to operate on something that I only have a link to the collection, not the instance I'm operating on. Now I'm saying that, it sounds silly, so I'll check.

I'm using backbone relational for the comments collection, so that's why you don't see a specific collection. It's created automatically thanks to the relational bit at the top. Got Add/Delete working now, so presume update will be fairly simple. Learning a lot....

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I don't have much experience with BB relational, but it doesn't sound right to me that you have to manage model ids explicitly. In fact, if you look into their getting-started section (https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational#getting-started) you'll see they define a zoo-animals relationship without declaring an idAttr for either model. It's also suspicious that in your code you have the same attr id name for both CommentModel and PostModel. Not sure that's right, but if it works for you then it's probably ok. Anyway, as you keep learning please post your findings.

Comment: Having the same attr id name for both things was def a problem, had to switch that out becuase it was getting confused between the two. It's just my db model is all posts (Comments are type 2). I'm still putting a few id's here and there, but I'll refactor as needed. Really wanted to get up and running, and considering how little code it's taken to do what I've done, I'm pretty happy overall!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think my response address's the specific issue I was having. I was doing it wrong essentially. Ignoring el, which solved everything.

Comment: Cool deal Chris. Glad to know you figured it out. Btw, there's also a cached jquery object for your view element called $el, so you may be able to do this.$el instead of $(this.el). Just more efficient.

Comment: Great to know!! (comment limit, although I do generally approve of multiple exclamations!